# Reduce dictionary of deque to single boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want d to evaluate to `True` iff all values in `d` are empty

```
from collections import deque

d = {'a': deque([1,2,3]), 'b': deque([1,2,3]), 'c': deque([1,2,3])}
```

I've tried `reduce` but I'm clearly missing something important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `not any(d.values())`

Comment: Peter Wood, can you enter your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Wood kindly pointed out, `not any(d.values())` does the trick nicely.